# Calculating standard deviation on list ignoring zeros using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, standard-deviation

I am having a list `pct_change`. I need to calculate std deviation on the list ignoring the zeros. I tried below code, but it is not working as expected.

```
import numpy as np
m = np.ma.masked_equal(pct_change, 0)
value = m.mask.std()
```

Input value: `pct_change`

```
0          0.00
1          0.00
2          0.00
3      18523.94
4      15501.94
5      14437.03
6      13402.43
7      18986.14
```

Code has to ignore 3 zero values and then calculate standard deviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to convert the `zeros` to `NaNs` and then use `np.nanstd` that would ignore the `NaNs` for the standard deviation computation  -

```
np.nanstd(np.where(np.isclose(a,0), np.nan, a))
```

Sample run -

```
In [296]: a
Out[296]: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18523.94, 15501.94, 14437.03, 13402.43, 18986.14]

In [297]: np.nanstd(np.where(np.isclose(a,0), np.nan, a))
Out[297]: 2217.2329816471693
```

Note that we are using `np.isclose(a,0)` because we are dealing with `floating-pt` numbers here and it's not a good idea to simply compare against `zeros` to detect those in a float dtype array.

Answer (score 4):

Filter for values unequal to zero first:

```
>>> a
array([     0.  ,      0.  ,      0.  ,  18523.94,  15501.94,  14437.03,
        13402.43,  18986.14])
>>> a[a!=0].std()
2217.2329816471693
```